# Does Selenium support testing of HTML5 elements?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

can anyone explain  to me reg the selenium support for testing of html5 elements?If yes can u explain how? I have searched the web but couldn't find any proper solution .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Means do you want to test HTML5 website using selenium?

Comment: Please provide a specific example.

Comment: yes i want to test HTML5 website using selenium

Comment: for example i want to test the login functionality in this link https://elasticbox.com/login/ which has htlm5 elements .how do i test for the presnce of the tooltip if the field is left blank

Comment: I doubt you can do that. Because the tooltip that is coming (In Chrome) isn't having any DOM. So I guess you can't even get handle to it.

Comment: Mostly should work, the new Drag and Drop within HTML5 won't work and nor will the `<input type=multi>` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't automate that. They are the tooltips that are coming from browser. For example:

1. Chrome
2. Firefox

provides them as tooltip which are browser specific and they aren't related to DOM. So you cant automate using Selenium.

Where as the error in Safari is shown as an animation (attached to the DOM), which you can automate.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the element you are looking to test. For example a rich element like a canvas is not suitable for testing using selenium as no elements within the canvas are exposed via the DOM. However elements such as a progress bar are testable using selenium as data about the element is contained within the DOM (progress bar value is stored).

Basically the question you need to ask yourself is, is the data I'm looking for located within the DOM of the page I am looking to test. If yes - Selenium should work fine. If no - you may need to look into other alternatives.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I was curious myself and created a fast recording with Selenium IDE, it all worked fine. I don't see why it wouldn't work.